# How much memory (RAM) can be allocated by an App on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, memory-management, max

we are planing an app for blackberry app world and will have to load lots of textures and audiofiles.
so we need to know how much memory the app can really allocate for a smarthphone with 64MB (RAM)

thx for answers!

Comment: sorry, yes i mean 64MB and edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check available memory before load:
[MemoryStats.html#getFree()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/MemoryStats.html#getFree()) - Amount of memory/strorage free
[Memory.html#getFlashFree()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Memory.html#getFlashFree())  - Bytes of free flash
[FileConnection.html#availableSize()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/javax/microedition/io/file/FileConnection.html#availableSize()) - The available size in bytes on a file system

Answer (score 1):

You can try to allocate as much memory as you need.  If there isn't enough available, it will throw an OutOfMemory runtime exception when you try to allocate memory.  That said, I don't think your app would be a good "citizen" on the phone if it tries to grab all available RAM.